# General doubts about Express-session middleware

Tags: mongodb, express, session, cookies, express-session

I am a complete beginner in the web and I have a lot of stable doubts which I hope you won't mind answering.

Ques1: Sir how my MongoDB store is clearing a session after the max-age or expiry time? Does the driver of connect-mongo have some async function that is called as an event whenever the session is expired or the MongoDB server has a special meaning for sessions collection or MongoDB have build-in methods that are doing so with the help of some async functions and all?  I implemented this manually for learning purposes and it was fun but how this thing is happening in the Express-session part I am amazed and very confused. Who is taking care of the expiry thing and all?

Ques2: Sir I don't understand the resave thing. I have done a lot of googles and came to know about resave and saveUninitialsied. I know what saveUninitialised means. It says don't save a new session unless and until the cookie is modified. Cool thing. Then people went on explaining about resave on StackOverflow and touch method but I don't get from there. What does it even mean if the database does not have a touch command initialised? Also does the resaving and other stuff happens on the database or from the command of my server to the database. It's my servers command on the database right? Or something is going on under the hood.

Ques3: Sir if I want to send more than 1 cookie to the user in express-session, is it possible and is it a professional practice? Or should I use cookie parse with res.cookie to send more than 1 cookie? Also, can I change the name of connect.sid to something else which is my next question?

Ques4: Sir I wanted to know if I can store more key-value pair as key and JSON in the cookie so I did something like this but the data is not stored in MongoDB as far as I have checked. So is the data stored in the cookie?

```
//creating the session
app.use(session({
    name: 'auth cookie', //Name of the cookie
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection }), //To store session-store as Mongoose,
    secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET, //Used to sign the cookie
    saveUninitialized: false, //If the user bounces off, don't create a session
    resave: false, //Touch method is implemented by MongoDB. I want to know more about this option
    cookie: {
        path: '/', //Where the cookies would be saved
        httpOnly: true, //Javascript on client cannot get access to cookies. Good for security.
        secure: false, //http service. Not strictly HSTS or HTTPS
        maxAge: 60*1000, //1 minute
        sameSite: true, //No XSRF
        name: 'Hobbit Holet', //This is how values are stored in the cookie for furture use
        age: '21' //This is how values are stored in the cookie for furture use
    }
}));
```

Ques5: Sir as you can see I have a secret. Now I can see the cookies on my browser. Now the cookie has some data and I have the secret key. So for debugging purposes and only in development mode is there a way I can decrypt the data inside the cookie by the secret key I am having here? If there is a way please share the algorithm used to hash or encrypt the data before sending.

Thank you, everyone and I am open to constructive criticism if I wrote something wrong or did any mistakes on my part in asking the question. I hope to get help as I am stuck here for the day.

Comment: On one of your questions, express-session uses a single cookie to store its session id.  It does not need or use more than that one cookie.  If you have a reason to have another cookie, then you can set that yourself and it will have nothing to do with express-session.

Comment: Thank you so much, sir. Just like res.cookie... right?

Comment: Yes, you can set the cookie with `res.cookie()`.

Comment: Too many questions in one question.  That makes it incredibly hard for anyone to write an answer because people feel like an answer has to be able to answer all your questions.  In general, you want to write questions that make it easy for people to write answers, not hard.

Comment: I thought these were just the basic things. So asking them by making different different questions would be irritating people. That's why I tried to put it into one complete pact. But if anyone can take time to even answer 1 question, it be very nice for me. Is this not a good protocol?

Comment: See [One post with multiple questions or multiple posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) and [Why isn't it good to ask multiple questions in one question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371614/why-isnt-it-good-to-ask-multiple-questions-and-answers-in-one-question)

Answer (score 0):

> Ques1: Does the driver of connect-mongo have some async function that is called as an event whenever the session is expired

no, mongoDB supports creating TIL (time to live) index. so when you set a `maxAge` using the "connect-mongo" module, it sets the TIL index for that session field. mongoDB automatically removes that field after the specified time

> Ques2: What does it even mean if the database does not have a touch command initialised

if `saveUninitialized` is `true`, then session will not be created (for any user) until some property is appended to the session.

if `resave` is `true`, then express session will resave (i.e. clear the session and resave) the session in the store/database, whenever user sends a request to the sever.

because some database will clear your sessions (stored in database) after a certain time. so, if your database (e.g. mongoDB) support touch command then express session will can prevent it by default, but if the database doesn't support the touch command then it's better to resave the session after some time so that it's not deleted before the specified expiry time.

> Ques3: should I use cookie parse with res.cookie to send more than 1 cookie? Also, can I change the name of connect.sid to something else

you can't send multiple sessionId cookie for a single user. if you want to send some other cookies then you can use the `res.cookie` method to do it, but it's better to store all the user related data in the session

you can change the default `connect.sid` cookie name to anything by using the `name` option.

**ex:**

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: "",
  name: "sessionId", // default is connect.sid
  ...
}))
```

> Ques4: but the data is not stored in MongoDB as far as I have checked

1. don't specify any user data while defining the session options.
2. cookie property (in session options) is used to store the cookie attribute for the sessionId cookie that will be stored in the users browser.
3. to store data to a session, add it to the session property itself

**ex:**

```js
req.session.name = 'Hobbit Holet',
age = '21'
```

> Ques5: is there a way I can decrypt the data inside the cookie by the secret key

the sessionId cookie DOES NOT contain any user data, the user data is stored on the session (in server-side). even if you decode the value from the cookie (that is store in user's browser), it will be a useless random string